# NGINX 1.11.5 image filter module unknow directive

Tags: nginx, module

I have NGINX v 1.11.5 this is the response from nginx -V:

```
    nginx version: nginx/1.11.5 built with OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_slice_module --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/headers-more-nginx-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge --add-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-development-kit --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/ngx-fancyindex --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nchan --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-lua --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-upload-progress --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-dynamic-module=/build/nginx-VZwxAJ/nginx-1.11.5/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

as you can see I have

```
--with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic
```

when I insert into my configuration file, under location, the tag image_filter I get this error

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "image_filter" in ....
```

any idea?

thanks

--update--
configuration:

```
location ~ "^/media/(?<width>\d+)/(?<image>.+)$" {
    alias /var/www/images/$image;
    image_filter resize $width -;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality 75;
    image_filter_buffer 8M;
}
```

Comment: what is your `nginx` config where image_filter is used?

Comment: location ~ "^/media/(?<width>\d+)/(?<image>.+)$" {
      alias /var/www/images/$image;
      image_filter resize $width -;
      image_filter_jpeg_quality 75;
      image_filter_buffer 8M;
  }

Comment: did you please resolve this in the end?

Comment: Have you found the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2):

I solved unknown directive "image_filter" by manually setting path to this module into the nginx.conf file

```
load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the top of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

```
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf;

or

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
```